# Best way to get List<LocalDate> from Interval

Tags: java, jodatime

What is the best way to get a `List<LocalDate>` from an `Interval` with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) ?

For example :

```
Interval interval = new Interval(new LocalDate(2015, 01, 01).toDate().getTime(), new LocalDate(2015, 01, 05).toDate().getTime()); //Maybe not the best way to create an Interval...

List<LocalDate> listLocalDate = getListLocalDateFromInterval(interval);

for (LocalDate localDate : listLocalDate) {
    System.out.println(localDate);
}
```

Expected result :

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post any experimenting code you have. Post code that you found in tutorials (if any). Give some context: Why you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
LocalDate from = interval.getStart().toLocalDate();
LocalDate to = interval.getEnd().toLocalDate();
List<LocalDate> lds = new ArrayList<>(Days.daysBetween(from, to).getDays());
for(LocalDate c = from ; c.isBefore(to) || c.isEqual(to) ; 
      c = c.plusDays(1)) {
    lds.add(c);
}
```